# Ruby on Rails - Masthead div in application.html.erb, render in all pages except homepage?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I tried reading guides.rubyonrails but I cant seem to figure this out:

I have a masthead in my application.html.erb file in my rails 4.0 application.
I want the masthead div to be rendered in all pages except the homepage.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use different layout for homepage, the one which doesn't contain the masthead?

Comment: Thanks for the response geeky_sh
How do I define another file to be used as the layout other than application.html erb?
As far as I know application.html.erb is loaded as a wrapper for all pages generated by RoR?

Comment: You can specify layout while rendering the view. Have a [look](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a conditional ruby statement like

```
<% unless current_page?(root_url) %>
    <div>Your html code</div>
<% end %>
```